# receiving data in express backend

Tags: express

i have created express app using express generator which i want to receive data from my client. ive tried a number of scripts from the internet but none seems to work. please assist. this is currently what im trying to use

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express.Router();

async function httpRequest(){
  try {
    const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}


module.exports=app;
```

Comment: You are not initializing express correctly. See [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

install body-parser from npm first
`npm install body-parser --save`

Add this code in your application entry point (Ex: `app.js` or `index.js`) whatever it is.

```
const express = require('express'), 
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```